# macOS : stream a "false" prerecorded image/video to my webcam

Tags: macos, video, camera, streaming, webcam

I want to feed my webcam with a "false" prerecorded image/video (as allowed camcamx soft on mac).

How to do ? Do you know a method or software? An alternative to camcamx ?

I use MacOS 10.11 Sierra on MacBook Pro 2014
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can't feed your webcam anything - it's not a display device.  You have to send your RECIPIENT the feed you want them to see.

Answer (score 8):

## Open Broadcaster Software

Thanks to [work by](https://github.com/johnboiles/obs-mac-virtualcam) John Boiles, can use [Open Broadcaster Software (OBS)](https://obsproject.com/) and it's virtual camera feature on macOS.

OBS is free and open source.

Comment: This works well and allows 1-click changes between live video and pre-recorded videos.

Answer (score 2):

ManyCam is an alternative to camcamx

https://manycam.com